# Ruby: group an array of ActiveRecord objects in a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'd like to group an array of ActiveRecord objects into a hash with an interface that's simple to query after an SQL statement that looks like the following:

```
SELECT name,value from foo where name IN ('bar', 'other_bar') LIMIT 2;
```

After that query, I want a hash where I can go:

```
foo[:bar] # output: value1
foo[:other_bar] # output: value2
```

What's the best way to collect the objects with ActiveRecord and group them so I can use the interface above?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Rails 2

```
foos = Foo.all :select => "name, value",
               :conditions => ["name in (?)", %w(bar other_bar)],
               :limit => 2
```

In Rails 3

```
foos = Foo.where("name in (?)", %w(bar other_bar)).select("name, value").limit(2)
```

Then

```
foo = Hash[foos.map { |f| [f.name.to_sym, f.value] }]
```

or

```
foo = foos.inject({}) { |h, f| h[f.name.to_sym] = f.value; h }
```

or in Ruby 1.9

```
foo = foos.each_with_object({}) { |f, hash| hash[f.name.to_sym] = f.value }
```

Answer (score 4):

If I understood you correctly:

```
foo = Hash[Foo.find(:all, :limit => 2, :select => "name, value", :conditions => ["name in ('bar', 'other_bar')"]).map { |s| [s.name.intern, s.value] }]
```

Comment: Note that this will only work for Ruby 1.9; for Ruby 1.8 you must use `Hash[ *foo.flatten ]`.

Comment: @rubyprince is right, I tested this in a script/console running 1.8.7.

Comment: My mistake, I should have said 1.8.6; Ruby 1.8.7 is such a bizarre beast.

Answer (score 1):

```
Hash[result.map { |r| [r[:name].to_sym, r[:value]] } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
models.inject({}) {|h,m| h[ m.name.to_sym ] = m.value; h }
```