# Split array. Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, split

Could you help me please with some problem? 
I have array from database like this

```
 str = Hiring::Tag.all
  Hiring::Tag Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `hiring_tags`.* FROM `hiring_tags`
=> [#<Hiring::Tag id: 1, name: "tag1", created_at: "2013-12-10 11:44:39", updated_at: "2013-12-10 11:44:39">,
    #<Hiring::Tag id: 2, name: "tag2", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>,
    #<Hiring::Tag id: 3, name: "tag3", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>,
    #<Hiring::Tag id: 4, name: "wtf", created_at: "2013-12-11 07:53:04", updated_at: "2013-12-11 07:53:04">,
    #<Hiring::Tag id: 5, name: "new_tag", created_at: "2013-12-11 10:35:48", updated_at: "2013-12-11 10:35:48">]
```

And I need to split this array like this:

```
    data:[{id:1,name:'tag1'},{id:2,name:'tag2'},
          {id:3,name:'tag3'},{id:4,name:'wtf'},{id:5,name:'new_tag'}]
```

Help me please!

Comment: It's already answered [Ruby: group an array of ActiveRecord objects in a hash][1]




  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490582/ruby-group-an-array-of-activerecord-objects-in-a-hash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution:

```
Hiring::Tag.all.map {|h| {id: h.id, name: h.name} }
```

See [the documentation for map](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-map).

Answer (score 3):

if you use ActiveRecord 4.0

```
Hiring::Tag.pluck(:id, :name).map{ |id, name| {id: id, name: name} }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code.

```
Hiring::Tag.all.inject({}) { |h, f| h[f.name.to_sym] = f.value; h }
```

OR

```
Hiring::Tag.all.map { |f| [f.name.to_sym, f.value] }]
```